# Printing contents of DataFrame returned from function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following function:

```
 import pandas as pd
    def foo():
        d1 = {'data1': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
        d2 = {'data2':  [20, 30, 40]}
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
        return df1, df2
df1, df2 = foo()
```

I am trying to get the following:

```
Results for df1:

   data1
    A
    B
    C

Results for df2:

    data2
    20
    30
    40
```

I tried some code below but didn't get me what I want (shows index, datatype and not very well aligned):

```
c = {'results for df1': df1,
     'results for df2': df2
    }
for a, b in c.items():
    print(a, b)
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your indentation, create a function that iterates over the `df` and prints its content without inserting extra data information like `itertuples`, use a number of `spaces` instead of `\t` to accomplish the padding you want, `\n` means newline, so something like this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd

def foo():
    d1 = {'data1': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
    d2 = {'data2':  [20, 30, 40]}
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
    return df1, df2



def print_df(df, name):
    print(f'Results for {name}:\n')

    for column in df:
        print(f'\t{column}')
        for _, row in df.itertuples():
            print(f'\t{row}')

        print('\n')

dfs= foo()
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    print_df(df, f'df{i + 1}')
```

This will output:

```
Results for df1:

        data1
        A
        B
        C


Results for df2:

        data2
        20
        30
        40
```